# Attempt to execute a script as a function

Tags: matlab

There is a script I have been trying to run and the error it produces is

> Attempt to execute SCRIPT Master_nusery_algorithm as a function

Any ideas with how I can solve this.

Here is a copy of the script

```
mangnursery = mangrovenurseries(map,mangrovefringe,40,20,500,830);
```

Comment: Your second snippet is a call to a function with arguments, not a script. If it's a function you want, make sure it is defined as such.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a proper function definition at the top of the file.  This is a good readme:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html

Specifically, try something like this at the top of your mangrovenurseries function:

```
function mangnursery = mangrovenurseries(map,mangrovefringe,param1, param2, param3, param4)
```